# grep for multiple strings in files, and then list the files in the order of size

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am in a folder with lots of `.txt` file, I would like to find all the files which contain both `stringA` and `stringB` (not necessarily on the same line), then list these files in the order of the size (from small to big)

I have tried the follows, but it doesn't work:

```
ls -lS | for f in *; do grep -q stringA $f && grep -l stringB $f; done
```

Does anyone have a good idea?

Comment: Usually I use `find -iname '*.txt' | xargs grep -ne str1 -e str2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GNU find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec grep -q stringA {} \; -exec grep -q stringB {} \; \
        -printf '%10s %p\n' | 
    sort -n
```

Comment: The `printf` arg to `find` is not POSIX, but this is a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) (portable and no problem with space in filenames) :

```
perl -Mautodie -wle '
    for (<"*.txt">) {
        open my $fh, "<", $_;
        my @list = <$fh>;
        close $fh;
        if (grep { /stringA/ } @list and grep { /stringB/ } @list) {
            $h->{$_}->{size} = (stat($_))[8];
        }
    }
    END{
        print join "\n", sort { $h->{$a}->{size} <=> $h->{$b}->{size} } keys %$h;
    }
'
```

Comment: Portable is nice, but loading the entire file into an array and then using `grep` in boolean context (twice) is pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

#### Method #1

You could use the following chain:

```
$ grep -l stringA * | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 grep -l stringB | xargs du | sort -nr
```

The `tr` converts the output of `grep` so that if any filenames include spaces they'll be protected going forward. Everything else is pretty straight-forward. The use of `xargs` to run the output from a previous command through the next command, is a typical pattern in Unix.

You can forego the `tr` bit and make use of `grep`'s `-Z` switch.

```
$ grep -lZ stringA * | xargs -0 grep -l stringB | xargs du | sort -nr
```

#### Example

```
$ grep -lZ stringA * | xargs -0 grep -l stringB | xargs du | sort -nr
9220    stringA99stringB.txt
8196    stringA88stringB.txt
7172    stringA77stringB.txt
6148    stringA66stringB.txt
5124    stringA55stringB.txt
4100    stringA44stringB.txt
3076    stringA33stringB.txt
2052    stringA22stringB.txt
1028    stringA11stringB.txt
4   stringAspacestringB.txt
```

#### Method #2

Similar approach except instead of the use of `du | sort` just pipe the output to `ls -lS` similar to your approach.

```
$ grep -lZ stringA * | xargs -0 grep -l stringB | xargs ls -lS
```

#### Example

```
$ grep -lZ stringA * | xargs -0 grep -l stringB | xargs ls -lS
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 9437200 Aug  6 15:15 stringA99stringB.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 8388624 Aug  6 15:15 stringA88stringB.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 7340048 Aug  6 15:15 stringA77stringB.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 6291472 Aug  6 15:15 stringA66stringB.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 5242896 Aug  6 15:15 stringA55stringB.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 4194320 Aug  6 15:15 stringA44stringB.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 3145744 Aug  6 15:15 stringA33stringB.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 2097168 Aug  6 15:15 stringA22stringB.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 1048592 Aug  6 15:15 stringA11stringB.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml      32 Aug  6 15:35 stringAspacestringB.txt
```

#### Method #3

This one makes use of `grep`'s ability to use Perl's regular expression engine (PCRE).

```
$ grep -Pzol "(?s)stringA.*stringB" * | xargs ls -lS
```

This method is a bit slower because the file is being converted so that it's end of lines are terminated with null characters (`\0`) instead of newlines (`\n`).

- `-P` activate perl-regexp for grep (a powerful extension of regular extensions)
- `-z` suppress newline at the end of line, substituting it for null character. That is, grep knows where end of line is, but sees the input as one big line.
- `-o` print only matching. Because we're using `-z`, the whole file is like a single big line, so if there is a match, the entire file would be printed; this way it won't do that.

In regexp:

- `(?s)` activate PCRE_DOTALL, which means that `.` finds any character or newline

#### References

- [Regex (grep) for multi-line search needed [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed)

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` and GNU tools:

```
grep -lZ -- stringA *.txt(oL) | xargs -r0 grep -l -- stringB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 egrep -l '(stringA|stringB)' * | xargs ls -1S
```

`egrep` allows for regular expressions, so the above will search for stringA OR stringB in all files, the `-l` option tells egrep to just output the files matched (and supress the output of the matching lines). Piping it to `xargs ls -1S` will pass all the files matches to `ls -1S`. `-1` tells ls to list one file per line and `-S` tells ls to sort by file size rather than by name.

**EDIT** Oops that's an OR (misread of the question).

In which case an adaption of sputnick's solution to use two greps

```
grep -l stringA * | xargs grep -l stringB | xargs -ls -1S
```

(at least getting around `du` and `sort` there's one less process :)

Comment: This is wrong in two ways: 1) the OP ask for both strings on each file; 2) the command fails on filenames containing spaces

Comment: OP asked a *AND*, not a *OR*